# MYSQL query to count table row

Tags: mysql, count, row

I made a program with this code:

```
select DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Birth_Date, INTERVAL '55 - 1' YEAR_MONTH), '01-%m-%Y')
AS Retire_Date
FROM employee
```

The question is how can I count amount of record `Retire_Date` in this month (example: February, 2016)?

NOTE : `retire_date` column isn't exist on database data

Comment: select count(*) from table where year(retire_date) = 2016 and month(retire_date) = 2 is this what you mean?

Comment: yes similar like that, but i want be dynamic depend on current date. So can counting automatically if month or year has change

Comment: oh , one more. Column 'retire_date' isn't exist, i create that with query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you want a query that returns how many people are retiring/retired in this the current month so:

```
SELECT count(*)
from employee
where year(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Birth_Date, INTERVAL '55 - 1' YEAR_MONTH), '01-%m-%Y')) = year(curdate())
      and month(DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(Birth_Date, INTERVAL '55 - 1' YEAR_MONTH), '01-%m-%Y')) = month(curdate())
```

Is this what you meant?

Comment: yes, that what i mean. But Retire_date column isn't exist on my database

Comment: Ok I'm not using retire_date I changed the query to use your format. @PramestyJaya

Comment: Would be helpful if you gave me the error you know.. @PramestyJaya

Comment: oh i see, my mistake. I didn't write it correctly, thanks man !!